# mysql (5.7.17) crashes on one specific query

Tags: mysql, crash, mysql-5.7

We have one java application, which uses mysql db as back end.
Mysql 5.7.17 is installed on windows server 2012 R2 Standard

The issue is that our java application crashes mysql database, 
We enabled logs and found out that there is this specific query that crashes mysql.

If I copy this query from the logs and run it in Workbench it crashes mysql and I get "Lost connection to mysql during query"

I tried increasing , max packet size, net read timeout to no avail.

To drill further , I installed same version mysql on another VM windows server 2012r2 standard , and here the query works fine, without any issues.

below is the query from the logs:

```
select userorgani0_.id as id1_16_,
userorgani0_.authority as authorit2_16_,
userorgani0_.organization_module_id as organiza3_16_, 
userorgani0_.user_id as user_id4_16_ 
from user_organization_module userorgani0_
where userorgani0_.organization_module_id='2c9e85c75a4025ed015a402b72040004' 
and userorgani0_.user_id='1rhdhdwi22c23214kcskcsk'
```

Could you please help me here.

regards, 
RVS

Comment: How large is this table?  Do you have indices on the columns involved in the `WHERE` clause?  If not, and you add them, the query might speed up dramatically and the connection might not be dropped.

Comment: Hey Tim,  thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that, this table has only one row in it and only 6-7 columns..so i guess no much data to process..still it crashes..to add more information: When the mysql crashes, I see below error message in Event viewer..."  Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program mysqld.exe because of this error.

Program: mysqld.exe
File: "

Comment: Anyone any ideas, on how to troubleshoot this

Comment: If I were you, I would get the query working first on Workbench.  Start by just doing `SELECT * FROM user_organization_module`.  If this doesn't work, then perhaps the table/database have become corrupted.  If it does work, then slowly add the complexity back to the query.

Comment: Will give it a try, Another thing I observed is, the other server on which I installed mysql, started crashing after a while , same query crashed it ,which was working earlier.. This link https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html says that mysql 5.7 is not supported on windows server 2012 R2, shoudl that cause an issue

Comment: I ran the above query using different combination, it only fails when there is an AND operator used..serorgani0_.organization_module_id='2c9e85c75a4025ed015a402b72040004' 
and userorgani0_.user_id='1rhdhdwi22c23214kcskcsk'...If i do a select * from table, select some columns from tables and other combinations, it works, only using AND fails

Comment: So are you saying that each `WHERE` condition, separately, works, but it crashes with both?

Comment: Hey Tim, Thanks for your help, we have resolved the issue..The Java team changed something in their code to modify the DDL on the database schema,...they said that the issue was due to multiple tables getiing opened recursively due to foreign keys ....and refered this link....https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65384